# linq update: "Row not found or changed." exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

When I try to Update or Delete a single selected item, it throws a "Row not found or changed." exception. Basically I only did a linq query and use most of the auto-generate function.  I added LinqDataSource1_ContextCreated function, but it does not help.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
               AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" 
               DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1" Width="100%" 
               onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="JobId" HeaderText="JobId" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="JobTitle" HeaderText="JobTitle" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Summary" HeaderText="Summary"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Detail" HeaderText="Detail" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyName" HeaderText="CompanyName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyEmail" HeaderText="CompanyEmail" />
            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="IsTop" HeaderText="IsTop"   />
            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="IsShown" HeaderText="IsShown" />
              <asp:BoundField DataField="PostDate" HeaderText="PostDate" 
                ApplyFormatInEditMode="True" DataFormatString="{0:MMM,dd,yy}" 
                HtmlEncode="False" ReadOnly="True"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" HeaderText="UserName" ReadOnly="True"/>

    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource1" runat="server" 
           ContextTypeName="JobPostDataContext" EntityTypeName="" 
           onselecting="LinqDataSource1_Selecting" TableName="JobLists" 
           EnableDelete="True" EnableUpdate="True" >
            </asp:LinqDataSource>

  protected void LinqDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs e)
    {
        JobPostDataContext db = new JobPostDataContext();

        var query = from uM in db.aspnet_Memberships
                    join uD in db.UserDetails
                    on uM.UserId equals uD.UserId
                    join u in db.aspnet_Users
                    on uM.UserId equals u.UserId
                    join jL in db.JobLists
                    on uM.UserId equals jL.UserId
                    where u.UserName == Request.QueryString["UserName"]

                    select new
                    {
                        jL.JobId,
                        jL.JobTitle,
                        jL.Summary,
                        jL.Detail,
                        jL.CompanyName,
                        jL.CompanyEmail,
                        jL.PostDate,
                        jL.IsTop,
                        jL.IsShown,
                        u.UserName
                    };

         e.Result = query;
    }

    protected void LinqDataSource1_ContextCreated(object sender, LinqDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
    {

        JobPostDataContext db = e.Result as JobPostDataContext;

        System.Data.Linq.DataLoadOptions dl = new System.Data.Linq.DataLoadOptions();

        dl.LoadWith<JobList>(d => d.JobId);

        db.LoadOptions = dl;

    }
```

Row not found or changed. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.Linq.ChangeConflictException: Row not found or changed.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

> [ChangeConflictException: Row not
>   found or changed.]
>   System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode
>   failureMode) +996823
>   System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode
>   failureMode) +378
>   System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges()
>   +23    System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinqToSqlWrapper.SubmitChanges(DataContext
>   dataContext) +9
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinqDataSourceView.UpdateDataObject(Object
>   dataContext, Object table, Object
>   oldDataObject, Object newDataObject)
>   +115    System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinqDataSourceView.UpdateObject(Object
>   oldEntity, Object newEntity) +262
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.QueryableDataSourceView.ExecuteUpdate(IDictionary
>   keys, IDictionary values, IDictionary
>   oldValues) +115
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ContextDataSourceView.ExecuteUpdate(IDictionary
>   keys, IDictionary values, IDictionary
>   oldValues) +100
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinqDataSourceView.ExecuteUpdate(IDictionary
>   keys, IDictionary values, IDictionary
>   oldValues) +41
>   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Update(IDictionary
>   keys, IDictionary values, IDictionary
>   oldValues,
>   DataSourceViewOperationCallback
>   callback) +95
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleUpdate(GridViewRow
>   row, Int32 rowIndex, Boolean
>   causesValidation) +1226
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleEvent(EventArgs
>   e, Boolean causesValidation, String
>   validationGroup) +716
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.OnBubbleEvent(Object
>   source, EventArgs e) +95
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object
>   source, EventArgs args) +37
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow.OnBubbleEvent(Object
>   source, EventArgs e) +121
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object
>   source, EventArgs args) +37
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs
>   e) +125
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +169
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +9
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument)
>   +13    System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection
>   postData) +176
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5563

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not setting

```
 EntityTypeName="JobLists"
```

And then in your select selecting jl ?

I.e.:

```
protected void LinqDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs e) 
{
    JobPostDataContext db = new JobPostDataContext();

    var query = from uM in db.aspnet_Memberships
                join uD in db.UserDetails
                on uM.UserId equals uD.UserId
                join u in db.aspnet_Users
                on uM.UserId equals u.UserId
                join jL in db.JobLists
                on uM.UserId equals jL.UserId
                where u.UserName == Request.QueryString["UserName"]

                select jl;


     e.Result = query;
}
```